# Why isn't external shared library getting linked into my APK?

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

I have a small Android project with a CMake file that pulls in an external native .so file.  It uses the same technique I've used for other projects and those projects had no problems.

In this case, the 'library.so' file is getting copied into the 'cmake/debug' directory as expected, but is not being linked into the actual APK.  Is there some hidden setting somewhere that must be set in order for it to be linked with the APK?

Here's the cmake file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
add_library( native-lib SHARED ./native-lib.cpp )
find_library( log-lib log )
 
add_library( libMyLib SHARED IMPORTED )
set ( MYLIB_SO_DIR C:/MYLIB/ARM64/ )
set_target_properties( libMyLib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${MYLIB_SO_DIR}/libMyLib.so )
target_link_libraries( native-lib libMyLib ${log-lib} )
```

Here's the Android manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.PackagingOnlyProject">
 
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:extractNativeLibs="true">
 
  <activity android:name="android.app.NativeActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
 
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
 
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
        android:value="libMyLib" />
   </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

And here's the build.gradle.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}
 
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"
    android.ndkPath "C:/Development/Android/NDK"
 
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.PackagingOnlyProject"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk.abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
 
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++14"
            }
        }
    }
 
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
 
        debug {
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            renderscriptDebuggable true
        }
    }
 
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
 
    packagingOptions{
        doNotStrip "*/arm64-v8a/*.so"
    }
 
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs += 'native-lib/src'
        }
    }
 
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
        }
    }
}
 
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Show some code?

Comment: Ok. Added the relevant parts.

Comment: Old version of the gradle plugin?

Comment: Using 4.1.2 according to the "other" grade file.